# Cordova WebView's localStorage not accessible in Android 7?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage

I have build an Cordova App 
(cordova -v 7.0.1, cordova-android 6.1.0).

That includes autostart. Which means when DEFINED, in the app, Bluetooth devices are connected to, the app will start.

The way this was done:

1. Save bluetooths address in localStorage (file__0.localstorage).//JS side
2. BroadcastReceiver, on bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED. Retrieve localStorage (file__0.localstorage) if connected device match device in our LocalStorage Start app.// Native side

This was compiled in the end of 2016. And it worked til now, even with newer, software wise, devices.

I decided to do some app updates, and now it stopped working. After some debugging I saw I can't read file__0.localstorage. This is what I have so far:

```
    File dataDir = new File(context.getFilesDir().getParent());
    File appWebViewFilesDir = new File(dataDir, "app_webview/Local Storage/file__0.localstorage");

    Log.d(TAG, "Absolute path is " + appWebViewFilesDir.getAbsolutePath());
    //Result (rooted phone): path is given.
    //Result (UNrooted phone): path is given.

    Log.d(TAG, "Fine name is " + appWebViewFilesDir.getName());
    //Result (rooted phone): name is given.
    //Result (UNrooted phone): name is given.

    Log.d(TAG, "Is file Readable " + appWebViewFilesDir.canRead());
    //Result (rooted phone): true.
    //Result (UNrooted phone): false.

    Log.d(TAG, "Tring to set file to readable? " +appWebViewFilesDir.setReadable(true));
    //Result (rooted phone): true.
    //Result (UNrooted phone): false.

    Log.d(TAG, "Tring to set file to readable for all users? " + appWebViewFilesDir.setReadable(true, true));
    //Result (rooted phone): true.
    //Result (UNrooted phone): false.

    Log.d(TAG, "Is file Readable " + appWebViewFilesDir.canRead());
    //Result (rooted phone): true.
    //Result (UNrooted phone): false.

    Log.d(TAG, "Does this file exist " + appWebViewFilesDir.exists());
    //Result (rooted phone): true.
    //Result (UNrooted phone): false.
```

Any ideas when has this changed?

Any ideas how can I make localStorage file__0.localstorage accessible without having to root the devices?

Is possible to solve this without having to implement a new data storage system?

P.S. Data Persistence is not that important in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really an Android 7 issue. The localstorage seems to depend on the webview. And the webview can be upgraded independently.

> Is possible to solve this without having to implement a new data
>   storage system?

Yes. file__1.localstorage was a SQLLite db. Now, in the same folder, `app_webview/Local Storage` you should find another folder, `leveldb`. [LevelDB](http://leveldb.org/) is a database created by google. You can use a java wrapper, [leveldb-android](https://github.com/hf/leveldb-android) for example, to access it. And then you should use the iterator to iterate over the entries, looking for the one you need. Calling `get()` returned `null` in my case.